# distance used for Image comparaison

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was wondering what kind of formula I could use to compare 2 images.
I usually ue the Mean Square Error (or PSNR) but this isn't good enough.
I need to find a formula that return a very big distance between an image A and its pixellated (or blurred) version B, but I don't know how to proceed.
Has anyone an idea?

Comment: I suggest that you ask this question on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ instead, since it's less about matlab, and more about image processing.

Comment: Also [asked on DSP](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/188/distance-used-for-image-comparaison). Please don't do that, flag to have a moderator migrate the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an edge detection on the images, and use those for your PSNR comparison.